# Whats the difference between location and viewport coordinates when geocoding with google API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new with using the Google maps geocoding API. I gave it an address and have a few different coordinates in the response. Why are there different coordinates?

[image]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderGeometry

Answer (score 1):

**More on Viewports:** https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Viewports

"In a geocoding request, you can instruct the Geocoding service to prefer results within a **given viewport (expressed as a bounding box)**. You do so within the request URL by setting the bounds parameter. Note that biasing only prefers results within the bounds; if more relevant results exist outside of these bounds, they may be included.

The bounds parameter defines the latitude/longitude coordinates of the southwest and northeast corners of this bounding box using a pipe (|) character to separate the coordinates."

---

Viewport allows you to create a boundary within a specific region, sort of like looking at a larger section of the map within a set of coordinates. Locations coordinates are giving you the exact spot of a location.

Comment: If I'm going to store the longitude and latitude I fetched from the geocoding API, which is more accurate? the viewport or the location of geometry?

Comment: @ajgo location of geometry will give you accurate coordinates. If I remember correctly.